# What does log4j2 file appenders use for file encoding/format?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

What file format does log4j2 use when it writes to rollingfileappender? Furthermore, is there a way to change it?  What I'd like to do use use UTF-16.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Charset is specified on the Layout. `AbstractStringLayout` defaults to UTF-8.](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.5/manual/layouts.html)

You should be able to change that by specifying `charset="UTF-16"` on the Layout configuration.

Comment: Thank you!  It did not occur to me it was part of the pattern as I was looking all over the appenders for it.  Information on layouts are [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)

Comment: +10.  It may be worth pointing out that most layouts including PatternLayout extend AbstractStringLayout so they all accept a charset parameter.

Comment: You are right! It works in my log4j2.xml `<PatternLayout pattern="<mypattern>" charset="UTF-8" />`

Answer (score 10):

Small correction on Ralph's answer: for PatternLayout the default charset is the *system default*. This is important because for example the Windows console won't be able to correctly display UTF-8 on Japanese Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you use log4j.properties, configure it as follow:

```
appender.rolling.layout.charset = UTF-16
```

or make the corresponding configurations in your xml configuration file.

Comment: You should provide a larger excerpt of your configuration, because the current content of your answer can give the wrong impression that `appender.rolling.layout.charset` is a universally valid configuration property. In reality `rolling` and `layout` are arbitrary identifiers.